# sql decode function

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-null

I have a query that join 2 tables and displays the name as follows:

```
select a.first_name||','||a.last_name as name, a.number as id, b.address
from student a, address b
where a.number = b.id;
```

In couple cases the name wouldnt have a value in student table. Ouput looks as:

```
Name      Id    Address
abc, def  100   CA
xxx,yyy   101   MA
,         102   PA
```

So I tried using decode like,

```
select decode(a.first_name||','||a.last_name,',','') as name, a.number as id, b.address
from student a, address b
where a.number = b.id;
```

But this return null for name fields in all the rows. I have to show null values for names when it doesnt exists. I need to get rid of the comma.

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?  Why doesn't your query use `JOIN`?

Comment: Third row shouldnt show comma for name field it should just be null.

Comment: I tried regexp_replace(a.first_name|| ',' || a.last_name,'[,]','') - this works but i want to use decode

Comment: Why decode ? I think ```CASE```is the best for this. What do you want to see if there is only a first name or only a last name ?

Comment: Do you have cases when only one of the first name or last name is `null`, and the other is not? What would you like to show in those cases? Note that if you say "just show the non-NULL name, without commas", that will create confusion - if you see the single value `'Li'`, how do you know if that was first name or last name in the original table?

Answer (score 1):

[`NVL2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions132.htm#SQLRF00685) function, which brings results for `not null` or `null` cases of the first argument, would suit well for your case in which a trailing comma is added whenever `first_name` is not null by through the second argument of the function(`s.first_name||','`) after whitespaces trimmed from that column's value

```
SELECT NVL2(TRIM(s.first_name),s.first_name||',','')||s.last_name AS name, 
       s."number" AS id, a.address
  FROM student s
  JOIN address a
    ON s."number" = a.id
```

If you suspect that there might have been some non-printable characters, then add a regular expression also such as

```
SELECT NVL2(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(s.first_name,'[^[:print:]]')),s.first_name||',','')||s.last_name AS name, 
       s."number" AS id, a.address
  FROM student s
  JOIN address a
    ON s."number" = a.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1d434bf9ea8d639ab8830a9ab8727afb)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Why not with TRIM:

```
    WITH demo_data AS ( SELECT 'abc' AS first_name, 'def' AS last_name, 100 AS id, 'CA' AS address FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'xxx' AS first_name, 'yyy' AS last_name, 101 AS id, 'MA' AS address FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL  AS first_name, NULL  AS last_name, 102 AS id, 'PA' AS address FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ddd' AS first_name, NULL  AS last_name, 103 AS id, 'CA' AS address FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL  AS first_name, 'eee' AS last_name, 104 AS id, 'MA' AS address FROM DUAL )
SELECT TRIM(',' FROM first_name||','||last_name) as name,
       id,
       address
  FROM demo_data;
```

Result:

```
NAME            ID AD
------- ---------- --
abc,def        100 CA
xxx,yyy        101 MA
               102 PA
ddd            103 CA
eee            104 MA
```

Comment: This will leave a trailing comma if `last_name` is null but first name isn't.  I don't know if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If trimType is not specified, it will default to BOTH. I have added the examples. No comma in the result in each case.

Answer (score 0):

What about NULLIF function -

```
select NULLIF(a.first_name||','||a.last_name, ',') as name, a.number as id, b.address
from student a, address b
where a.number = b.id;
```